# Where can I put holes in my yard?

Tags: lighting, outdoor

I bought string lights and I plan to put them in my small indoor/outdoor yard (I am not sure whether it is indoor or outdoor).

I used a strong magnet (see picture) to detect where have metal behind the paint, but I find many spots. I guess that they are plates for connection. I cannot drill through those areas where have metal plate.

My question is where I can drill holes to mount eye screws?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

https://ibb.co/jzXwYt1

https://ibb.co/W3ykkxF

https://ibb.co/dQ7ccVH

https://ibb.co/SP2dw2K

Comment: I'm confused. You mention a yard (which may be inside our outside, somehow), but show photos of a wall and a light device. Are you asking about drilling through the _wall_? What plates are you talking about? How is your home constructed? Please revise your question to clarify.

Comment: A small light string shouldn't need to be screwed into studs.  Small screws or nail-on clips that only penetrate the outer layer should be fine.  I feel like what you are trying to do is unclear.

Comment: I believe that you want to attach lights to the exterior wall and which might or might not be under cover. I see in your picture the exterior of the building with an overhang that protects the wall from weather. It looks to me like you have stucco and my understanding is that stucco is applied over a wire mesh which would be why your magnet seems to hold in most places. I believe that your question is more along the lines of: how do I find the studs? Is this accurate?

Answer (score -1):

I don't use magnets, or stud finders set to 'metal', ever. I use drill bits. **If there's protection plates, the drill bit will tell you that.**

I think you're finding screw heads. **Disclaimer : I live in EMT land**, so there's generally no concern beyond hitting a PVC pipe or low voltage comm.

If you have to push really hard, don't; relocate. Patching and painting my be required after all is said and done. That's why it sucks trying to hang something that won't cover your booboos. And why *'new construction'* people won't touch rehab jobs that begin and end with *'unforeseen circumstances'*. This is your can of worms; open it up:

You're going to have to do some recon... with a drill bit. **Bite the bullet and start making holes.** And use your intuition: It's an outside wall so it's *unlikely* there's any plumbing. And way up there would be a strange place for an electrical run, but anything's possible. - Henry Jones says: *"I don't know. WE'LL FIND OUT!"*

Comment: ... it could be an i-beam. Cut the tips off of drywall anchors and use shorter screws, if you have to.

Comment: "EMT land"  Emergency Medical Technician land?

Comment: @Steve Wellens Electrical metallic tubing, protecting any dangerous line-voltage wires.

Comment: "EMT land" is obvious to those who understand electrical work, but is totally meaningless to the OP who seems quite confused.